# srm.exe install shell extension: Fails with "Cannot cast the underlying exported value"

Tags: shell-extensions, sharpshell

I have written this simplistic shell extension (explorer context menu) with SharpShell:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[COMServerAssociation(AssociationType.AllFiles)]
public class SampleExtension : SharpContextMenu
{
    protected override bool CanShowMenu()
    {
        return true;
    }
    protected override ContextMenuStrip CreateMenu()
    {
        var menu = new ContextMenuStrip();
        var item = new ToolStripMenuItem
        {
            Text = "Hello world!"
        };
        menu.Items.Add(item);
        return menu;
    }
}
```

It works in debug with SharpShell Server Manager, but when I try to install it via `srm.exe` on command line I get:

```
srm.exe install ..\SampleExtension\bin\Debug\CountLinesExtension.dll -codebase  

System.ComponentModel.Composition.CompositionContractMismatchException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=Cannot cast the underlying exported value of type 'SharpShell.SharpShellServer (ContractName="SharpShell.ISharpShellServer")' to type 'SharpShell.ISharpShellServer'.
  Source=System.ComponentModel.Composition
  StackTrace:
       at System.ComponentModel.Composition.ExportServices.CastExportedValue[T](ICompositionElement element, Object exportedValue)
       at System.ComponentModel.Composition.ExportServices.GetCastedExportedValue[T](Export export)
       at System.ComponentModel.Composition.ExportServices.<>c__DisplayClassa`1.<CreateStronglyTypedLazyOfT>b__7()
       at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
       at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
       at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
       at ServerRegistrationManager.Application.<LoadServerTypes>b__2(Lazy`1 st)
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
       at ServerRegistrationManager.Application.InstallServer(String path, RegistrationType registrationType, Boolean codeBase)
       at ServerRegistrationManager.Application.Run(String[] args)
       at ServerRegistrationManager.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Probably a deployment problem. Maybe a GAC issue. Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14316978/compositioncontractmismatchexception-when-trying-to-use-mef-with-mvc-controller

Answer (score 3):

We ran in into the same issue. Turns out we were just not running srm.exe from the same directory as as our dll. Our dll included other dlls so it would fail to load that way. Once we ran srm.exe with our dlls all in the same directory, it worked.

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not seem to solve the problem on Windows 10 64bit.